# Inserting and updating data in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

So far all the Excel stuff revolves around opening a file, writing values to it and saving it.

Is there a way to update the data in the Excel (while it's opened) automatically?

Thanks!

P.S. I am looking for more information with respect to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Comment: Can you clarify a bit where the data is coming from, and how you use it in Excel? Are you trying to push data from an application that is running, into a workbook that is already open?

Comment: Are you trying to change the data that is in the Excel when you open it in your program, instead of just adding new stuff?

Comment: @Mathias, @Rox.

That's right. The excel workbook is opened and data on the worksheet will be constantly updated like a price feed or stock market rates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you're writing the data, but for reading data from Excel, this is what I do:

select the Range I need (can be from one cell to several rows and columns - it's a single cell here):

```
Excel.Range cell = m_worksheet.get_Range(_CellName(end, column), _CellName(end, column));
```

then get the values you need from the selected cell:

```
string value = cell.Value2.ToString().Substring(...);
```

you can also manipulate the colors if there are any:

```
if(Convert.ToInt32(cell.Interior.ColorIndex) == 6) //we have yellow background
```

be careful with colors if your users have Excel 2007, though. You'll have to use the RGB codes.

Also, while processign the Excel file, it's locked for other applications, I think. You'll have to check that for the 3rd party readign the values.

And for _CellName:

```
private string _CellName(int row, int col)
 {
      string result = "";
      if (col > 26) // for columns like 'AA' 
      {
           result = ((char)((char)(col / 26) + 'A' - 1)).ToString(); //get the first letter
      }
      result += ((char)((char)(col % 26) + 'A' - 1)).ToString(); //get the second/only letter
      return result + Convert.ToString(row);
 }
```

Comment: What is this _CellName? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it, I've used it all the time and forgot it was written by us: it returns the name of the cell in the Excel style format - "A1" for row 1, column 1. Will add the code to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Timer and have it restart for a periodic update or to do whatever.
This links describes the concept in detail. http://www.ehow.com/how_5052033_insert-timer-ms-excel.html
The way it would work in your case is to periodically allow you to get data from an external resource and then you could write some VBA code (Or a Macro) to update your worksheet.
Just like a stock ticker.

Comment: No, restarting is not an option. Because there is a 3rd party that's reading the values off.

Comment: I did not mean restart excel, I meant to restart the Timer once it had finished the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Why not access excel via ADO and treat it like a database?
http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

Comment: Because my external DDE application requires it the Excel application to be running constantly.